# What Load impedance to use for LC Filter before transformer?

Tags: transformer, low-pass

I have an inverter circuit in which I want to filter the output with an LC filter. Lets say the fundamental component that I want is 60Hz.

When designing a Low Pass LC filter, I need to use the load impedance. In this case it is 100 Ohms and it is placed on the high side of a transformer. The LC filter will be on the low side of the transformer.

Do I use the impedance value from the high side in my LC Low pass calculations or do I have to use the equivalent impedance that would be seen on the low side for the LC low pass calculations?

Shown below is an example circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use the reflected version from high to low. You turns ratio is 10:1 so the 100 ohms on the secondary will appear as 1 ohm on the primary.

But, you mention low pass filtering the 60 Hz - stay as far from the 60 Hz as you can because although the Ls and Cs you have drawn make a low pass filter, at resonance they are series resonant and will act as almost a dead short. The resonant frequency is: -

\$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$ Hz where L = L1 + L2 and C = C1 + C2

Just be aware of this in order to avoid burning stuff!!!

Comment: if you stay far from the 60Hz though, wouldn't there be alot of harmonics in my signal?

Comment: @user2464665 Yes there would so it's going to have to be a compromise or, you add several sections of filter but that also becomes complex to design. What you are trying to achieve is harder than you think basically but you can make life a little easier by having two LC low pass filters in series - at the moment, even though you have 2 inductors and 2 capacitors you are only forming one LC filter. You don't need the filter to be balanced because it feeds a transformer which will automatically rebalance your signal. I'd only use filters on the high voltage side too.